# WPF how to rotate a spherical image around z axis

Tags: wpf, image, rotation

i have a spherical image i want to rotate around its z-axis. I tried the following code, it works but image is rotating around x-axis.

```
<Image Name="logo" Grid.Column="1" Source="MyLogo.png"
           Width="140" Height="140" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
           >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="TransRotate" CenterX="70" CenterY="70" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Angle">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                     Storyboard.TargetName="TransRotate" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                     By="360" 
                     Duration="0:0:10"  
                     AutoReverse="False" 
                     RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `RotateTransform` doesn't rotate around the right axis then try `ScaleTransform`

```
<Image Name="logo" Grid.Column="1" Source="MyLogo.png"
       Width="140" Height="140" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform  x:Name="TransScale" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="TransScale"
                        To="-1" 
                        Duration="0:0:10"  
                        AutoReverse="True"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <SineEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

I've used [`RenderTransformOrigin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) on `Image` control instead of `CenterX` and `CenterY` because it's size independent. And I've added a sinusoidal [EasingFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751.aspx) for smoother animation.

Comment: Hi LPL, it rotates around Z axis , but it not appears like a 3D rotation. The problem is How to preserve spherical effect ?

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood your problem. But I've no idea how a rotation with RotateTransform could look like a 3D rotation. Could you specify what you want to achieve?

Comment: The image i have is a sphere , i want to rotate it around its center, that's it. the code above rotate sphere around its center but where it is rotating it is not like a ball but like a vertical line. If you have a spheric image try on it and you understand the problem.

Comment: If you want 3D animation, then you will need to use the 3D animation classes.